# Relating logs to their instructions

Tags: transactions, data, logs

For an individual transaction, how would you be able to relate a log to its corresponding set of instructions? I'm having difficulty finding a way to identify which logs belong to an instruction, especially in instances where there are nested inner instructions.

ie example instruction and logs for a transactions:

```
instruction 1
instruction 2
   -inner instruction 1
   -inner instruction 2
instruction 3
   -inner instruction 1
   -inner instruction 2
```

logs:

```
log a
log b
log c
log d
log e
```

...

How would you be able to identify that log `x` is related to instruction `x`? I noticed that some logs have an index (ie. "Program TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA invoke [2]") but am not entirely sure if that maps to an instruction in some way.

Answer (score 4):

Instructions in a transaction are processed in order. So the order you add the instruction to the transaction is the order the of the program logs. You can also use `msg!("Some Message")` to add additional Program Logs in your instructions.

Image is example of program logs for a transaction with multiple instructions
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When a program emits logs inside of a transaction, each log is effectively just added to a single, flat array of strings. So in order to actually determine the instruction that caused a program to emit a specific log is sort of difficult.

The way that the Solana explorer [parses and display](https://github.com/solana-labs/explorer/blob/master/app/utils/program-logs.ts) a transaction's logs is probably the best way to do. The explorer's parsing takes a few assumptions in its parsing:

- all the transaction logs are a simple array of strings
- each "simple string" log contains the address of the program that created the log (this is true because how the Solana rust code actually formats the logs)
- instructions within a Solana transaction are executed atomically (i.e. in order). this is how the Solana runtime is designed and always true
- at the completion of each program execution, there will always be a "success" message (the runtime does this automatically, and does not require the program developer to add this message). (this is the the [message to pay extra attention too](https://github.com/solana-labs/explorer/blob/master/app/utils/program-logs.ts#L84-L90) when processing the logs)

So if you loop over the simple array of string log values (type `String[]`):

- each log will have the program (`programId`) that executed it towards the beginning of the string
- when the programId changes, you know the runtime is processing a different program
- when the log is a "success" log, you know the program completed successfully. aka the instruction completed successfully (either the cpi or the non-cpi instructions)

Using this knowledge, you can loop over the array of string values, parsing out the instructions from a specific program and specific instruction within a transaction.

Note: there is potentially an edge case not covered by the explorer's parser. I believe that if a program decides to send extra logs that look like they were formatted similar enough, it could trick the explorer's simple parser to miss display the logs in the UI.